# how to get an app request to trigger a facebook app notification?

Tags: facebook, request

When a user sends a Facebook app request, I've seen it appear on my iPhone as a push notification from the Facebook app. Is there are way to trigger this from the developer side? Or is it 100% controlled by Facebook?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the developer side'? Do you want to send requests out from your dashboard? Requests need to be sent by an app (ios, android, web)

Answer (score 0):

The only available option is the app request . for more details https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/